# Getting function arguments in ida

Tags: ida, x86, idapython, ida-plugin

I'm trying to extract the callee arguments in my intel x86 binary using IDA Pro 7.3. I tried the following line:

```
ida_typeinf.get_arg_addrs(call_address)  # call address points at `call some_func`
```

For some reason, the call always returns `None`. Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Okay that's our sample code:

```
.text:0000000180002953                 lea     rcx, aSmiGetplatform ; "SMI_GetPlatformInfo"
.text:000000018000295A                 mov     r12b, 0FFh
.text:000000018000295D                 mov     ebx, 0FFFFh
.text:0000000180002962                 call    DBG_Func
```

Ida Python shell we enter:

```
Python> type ( idaapi.get_arg_addrs( 0x180002962 ) )
<class 'NoneType'>
```

And there it is
That 'none' is the problem.
Let's fix it.

Place cursor in 'DBG_Func' and press 'y' (or click Edit/Functions/Set Type)
it says:

```
void __fastcall DBG_Func();
```

Isn't DBG_Func supposed to receive and argument?
Well so the function type definition is wrong.
Change it to

```
void __fastcall DBG_Func(char *FunctionNameText);
```

and now test it again

```
Python> type (idaapi.get_arg_addrs( 0x180002962 ))
<class 'list'>
```

or

```
Python> idaapi.get_arg_addrs( 0x180002962 )
[0x180002953]
```

Wow finally problem solved!
At 0x180002953 there is the argument that is passed to the call.

Answer (score 1):

I have found out that if in the disassembler you give the type to the function that is being called, then the ida python function will work as it should.